# Is there a way to force an iOS6 app to use iOS7 style controls?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have an app which has had its UI designed for iOS7. Specifically, the UINavigationBar should have the "flat" look. In iOS6, the appearance is very different. Is there an easy way to make it retain the style of iOS7, or do I have to customize the bar?

[image: iOS7]

[image: iOS6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fake the iOS7 appearance by theming the controls in the app. You won't be able to get things like the blurs without a lot of effort, but the navigation bars and buttons are all pretty simple images so easy to replicate.

Strongly consider not supporting iOS6 at all though. There is a lot of difference between the two systems and you will burn a lot of time supporting a shrinking portion of probably non-active customers. Everyone that can run iOS6 can run iOS7. If they don't care enough to update their phone, they aren't going to care enough to download your app.

Comment: Good point. It's probably not worth it to take the extra effort, but I figured I'd check just in case there was a quick fix.

Comment: Thx, I'm one of those ppl that doesn't care enough to update their phone. ;)